# Core Plot: "Invalid context" error when tapping in chart

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-plot, cgcontext

I am using Core Plot 1.1 and iOS 7. In IB, I have set `User Interaction Enabled` to `YES` for the graph hosting view.

When running the app and tapping somewhere on the chart, I get the following warning in the console:

```
<Error>: CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace: invalid context 0x0. 
This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, 
is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an 
overall degradation of system stability and reliability. 
This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. 
It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I get this warning even before `barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` is called.

I have not changed my code for iOS 7 which worked fine in previous versions.

Is this a bug in Core Plot? How can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to a newer version of Core Plot. Version 1.1 is almost a year old. Version 1.4 was released recently and this problem is likely fixed in the newer version.